# python dash using variable as input for component

Tags: python, callback, plotly-dash

I am building a multi page dash app.  I can get my data via SQL query into a dataframe as a global variable initially, no worries there.  However, I am trying to then somehow get that data frame into dcc.Store so I can serialize it into JSON and pass that data around for the various dash pages.

I have searched here and the Internet and cannot locate how I can simply create a callback that would work in this way:

```
@app.callback(
    Output('user-data', 'data'),
    Input(<dataframe>)) ### THIS IS THE BIT I CANNOT FIGURE OUT HOW TO ACCOMPLISH
def clean_data(dataframe):
    return user_df.to_json(date_format='iso', orient='split')
```

Any Dash gurus out there, this is your time to shine.  I can really use your help.  Thanks.

P.S. This could also work if dash permitted the Input value to simply be a variable, something like this:

```
#SQL Query to use below in callback
master_data = """
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.<database name>
    WHERE <sqltablecolumn> = <variable value>
    """

@app.callback(
    Output('user-data', 'data'),
    Input(<string as Variable>)) 
def clean_data(**variable**):
    cstring = 'DRIVER=ODBC Driver 17 For SQL Server;Server=<servername;DATABASE=<dbname>;Trusted_Connection=yes;Regional=No'
    conn = pyodbc.connect(cstring)
    df = pd.read_sql(master_data,conn)
    user_df = df[<selection of needed columns from df>]
    user_df = user_df[user_df[colname] == **variable**]
    return user_df.to_json(date_format='iso', orient='split')
```

Comment: How are you retrieving the input data? If you're getting the input data from a dash component, each input can and must be passed to the callback function and then used inside it.

Comment: @ChuckTucker. Thanks for taking a look at this.  I actually solved it about two weeks after posting this.

Comment: @JohnTaylor, I'm having this same issue and curious how you solved it. Do you mind answering this question so people finding this via google can get help? Thanks!